# How can I change fontWeight of a placeholder in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, placeholder

In my SwiftUI project I have a placeholder that I want to be .heavy, but when I try to modify fontWeight it says that fontWeight is define on Text, what should I do?

This is the code:

```
TextField("", text: $MyModel.name[0])
    .placeholder(when: MyModel.name[0].isEmpty) {
        Text(player1)
            .font(Font.custom("Life Savers", size: 26))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
    .font(Font.custom("Life Savers", size: 26))
    //here it doesn't let me change the fontWeight to heavy
```

Comment: the code you show does not compile for me, I get `Value of type 'TextField<Text>' has no member 'placeholder'`
 In any case, for `TextField` you can use `.font(Font.custom("Life Savers", size: 26).weight(.heavy))`

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, it doesn't compile for you because I created a function placeholder with @ViewBuilder, anyway it's working now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `TextField` you use

```
.font(Font.custom("Life Savers", size: 26).weight(.heavy))
```